What is the rationality of a semi-honest adversary?
When I first came into contact with multi-party secure computing, I encountered the assumptions of semi-honest and malicious adversaries, and without much thought, I accepted them. However, I started asking me where the rationality of the semi-honest assumption lies in practice. Based on my understanding, adversaries can violate the content of the protocol without being discovered. Why do adversaries follow the protocol? Where has the rationality of this assumption been discussed or the context of semi-honest assumption first proposed?
Based on my understanding, I think there are possible reasons: 1. Violating the protocol does not allow them to obtain more information (I am not sure if this is correct); 2. In reality, the cost of violating the protocol being discovered is difficult to bear.

I found "When Is a Semi-honest Secure Multiparty
Computation Valuable?" by
Bhargava and Clifton to be an interesting read.

semi-honest adversary obeys the rules and observe, however, they can extract any information on their behalf. If you consider protocols, it is realistic; they are in the party, play, observe, and extract to gain advantage.
